# NSIS Resetting text and droplists upon button press

Tags: nsis

Hope you guys can help me out again. I have created a custom page, and in that page are sever text fieldsa and 2 droplists. I also have a clear button that if pressed it clears all the fields on the screen.

Note: I used the code from TestNotify.nsu in examples

The issue I have is one, when pressing clear the values are written to the ini file so upon reloading the program the last Fields used populate (Even if I press clear, I have to press it twice clear the ini file)

Second is how do I reset the droplist to the default I selected when pressing reset.

So the only section I am working on now is the clearbtn, so how can i reset the droplists to a specific value, and clear data from ini when pressing clear only once.

```
###Add Auto Start option

SetCompressor lzma
XPStyle on


!define FolderImages "Included\Images"

!define ImageIcon "Icon.ico"
!define ImageHDR "HDR.bmp"

!define PRODUCT_NAME "Test"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0"

!define MUI_ICON ".\${FolderImages}\${ImageIcon}"
Icon ".\${FolderImages}\${ImageIcon}"

!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include MUI.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

 !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
 !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP ".\${FolderImages}\${ImageHDR}"

Page custom SetCustom ValidateCustom

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function SetCustom

  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT  "Licence Key Generator" "Create or Read Licence Keys"


    #Hides the close button
    GetDlgItem $R0 $HWNDPARENT 1
    ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}


  InstallOptions::initDialog ".\UserProfiles.ini"
  ; In this mode InstallOptions returns the window handle so we can use it
  Pop $0
  ; Now show the dialog and wait for it to finish
  InstallOptions::show
  ; Finally fetch the InstallOptions status value (we don't care what it is though)
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function ValidateCustom

  # At this point the user has either pressed cancel or one of our custom buttons
  # We find out which by reading from the INI file
  ReadINIStr $0 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Settings" "State"
  StrCmp $0 0 cancelbtn 
  StrCmp $0 19 createbtn 
  StrCmp $0 20 readbtn 
  StrCmp $0 21 comparebtn 
  StrCmp $0 22 clearbtn 
  Abort # Return to the page

createbtn:
Abort # Return to the page

readbtn:
Abort # Return to the page

comparebtn:
Abort # Return to the page

clearbtn:

  #Text Field 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 6" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  #Text Field 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 8" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  #Text Field 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 10" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  #Drop List ------------------------------------------------------------<<<< 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 12" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTETX} 0 "STR:"

  #Text Field 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 14" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  #Drop List ------------------------------------------------------------<<<<
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 16" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  #Text Field 
  ReadINIStr $1 ".\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 18" "HWND"
  SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

  Abort # Return to the page

cancelbtn:

FunctionEnd

Section Dummy
SectionEnd
```

Comment: It would help if you post a minimal UserProfiles.ini

Comment: WM_SETTETX is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear a droplist by sending the [`CB_RESETCONTENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775878) message:

```
Var MyDir
Function .onInit
; Create example .ini
InitPluginsDir
StrCpy $MyDir $Temp ; Use something else in a real application, or use $PluginsDir.
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Settings" NumFields 4
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Type Button
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Left 0
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Right 50
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Top 0
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Bottom 14
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Text "&Clear"
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 1" Flags NOTIFY
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" Type Text
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" Left 0
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" Right 100
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" Top 15
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" Bottom 30
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" Type Droplist
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" Left 0
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" Right 100
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" Top 35
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" Bottom 99
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Type Button
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Left 55
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Right 105
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Top 0
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Bottom 14
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Text "&Add"
WriteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 4" Flags NOTIFY
FunctionEnd

Function SetCustom
InstallOptions::initDialog "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini"
; In this mode InstallOptions returns the window handle so we can use it
Pop $0
; Now show the dialog and wait for it to finish
InstallOptions::show
; Finally fetch the InstallOptions status value (we don't care what it is though)
Pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function ValidateCustom
# At this point the user has either pressed cancel or one of our custom buttons
# We find out which by reading from the INI file
ReadINIStr $0 "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Settings" "State"

StrCmp $0 1 clearbtn 
StrCmp $0 4 addbtn 
Abort # Return to the page


clearbtn:
    #Text Field 
    ReadINIStr $1 "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" "HWND"
    SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:"

    #Droplist Field
    ReadINIStr $2 "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" "HWND"
    SendMessage $2 ${CB_RESETCONTENT} 0 0
    DeleteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" "ListItems"
    DeleteIniStr "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" "State"

    Abort # Return to the page

addbtn:
    ReadINIStr $1 "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 2" "State"
    ReadINIStr $2 "$MyDir\UserProfiles.ini" "Field 3" "HWND"
    SendMessage $2 ${CB_ADDSTRING} 0 "STR:$1"
    SendMessage $2 ${CB_SELECTSTRING} 0 "STR:$1"

    Abort # Return to the page

FunctionEnd
```

You should not use relative .INI paths, that is just asking for trouble, use full paths!

Comment: I was using the relative path since this was just a testing app after I get it working I will adapt it and move it over to my real app. I will be using the $pluginsdir in my app.

Comment: $pluginsdir is deleted when you exit the installer so not using it will create extra bugs because you might not have a fresh .ini every time.